# CSS selector for id starting with hash (#)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm currently learning css and html and i've encountered an issue i never imagined i would, i've got to select an ID which ID is the following:

```
<header id="#Test">Testing Test</header>
```

Everytime i try to select this id on my css stylesheet there always seems to be an issue:

```
##Test {
    color: red;
}
```

I can't get the properties to work, i dont know how to select it, i would love if somebody would help me resolve this issue, thanks in advance!

Comment: Use only one hashtag in the CSS selector, and no hashtag in the `id` attribute

Comment: i would but its a task and i'm not allowed to touch the html document, only apply style to it, if i could i would tho.

Comment: I'm surprised that no one has mentioned that using the # in the id is invalid: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/syndata.html#characters

Comment: Rob, I checked that document but couldn't find the section that mentions that using # in an id is invalid. Can you point it out to me? Thanks. PS: Thanks OP had the same problem!

Answer (score 16):

CSS supports escaping

```
#\#Test {
    color: red;
}
```

Try this. Here one `#` is escaped to indicate it is part of the value of `id`

Answer (score 12):

You could use `[att=val]` selector.

```css
header[id="#Test"] {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<header id="#Test">Testing Test</header>
```

> [att=val] Represents an element with the att attribute whose value is
>   exactly "val".

Rerefence: [Attribute presence and value selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)

Comment: Note that attribute selectors are less specific than ID selectors *even when the attribute selector is based on the id attribute*, which, depending on whose camp you're in, is either an advantage or a disadvantage.

Comment: Besides being less specific, aren't attribute selectors significantly slower than ID selectors?

Comment: @Brian Nickel: They can be, depending on the implementation and depending on how many e.g. header elements there are in the page. Only profiling will tell you for certain.

Answer (score 10):

You can still use the ID selector [**by escaping the syntax characters**](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#cssescapes) like this:

```css
#\23Test1 {
  color: #F00;
}
#\23 Test2 {
  color: #080;
}
#\000023Test3 {
  color: #00F;
}
```

```html
<header id="#Test1">Testing Test</header>
<header id="#Test2">Testing Test</header>
<header id="#Test3">Testing Test</header>
```

The `23` in the above examples is the hexadecimal representation of `#` unicode code point value. The three variants above work as follows:

1. A non-hexadecimal character (the `T` in this case) indicates end of escape sequence.
2. A space indicates end of escape sequence.
3. Exactly 6 hexadecimal digits are used.

Comment: looks neat, but what do the number mean? is it a hashtag code or something?

Comment: @Vasko: the link explains in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Attribute selectors**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and more specific:

> [attr^=value]
>
> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value
>   is prefixed by "value".

```css
div[id^='#'] {
  background: red;
}
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="#Test">With ID starts with #</div>
<div id="Test">ID doesn't start with #</div>
```

This way will select all elements with `id` starting with `#`.